# pdfjs_viewer-rails - how to set HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf.js

I'm trying to use PDF.js with Rails with documents hosted by Amazon S3.
But I can't because of this message :

> Message: file origin does not match viewer's

I set up CORS to my S3 bucket as they said from the 
[ReadMe](https://github.com/senny/pdfjs_viewer-rails#setting-up-cors)

Unfortunately, I can't display PDF from S3.
For now, I'm using the viewer from local (localhost:3000)

What did I forget ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a viewer.js file in the library you need to override to make the file origin match the viewer origin:

app/assets/javascripts/pdfjs_viewer/viewer.js

There should be an array called HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS in that file. Just append the origins you need to that array (http://localhost:3000, https://www.yourwebsite.com, etc.)